# How to get HMR to work with Storybook (React/Preact components) in Astro project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, storybook, preact, astrojs

I've been able to get storybook to work with tailwind in an astro project,
by not using the official @astrojs/tailwind plugin (the preview mode won't render the tailwind styles with this plug), so instead I've made a regular tailwind with postcss install and added the @storybook/addon-postcss package. This way the preview mode works.

But now the issue is that the HMR is not working.

I'm wondering if anyone has been able to solve this, and if so how?

main.js

```
/** @type { import('@storybook/preact-vite').StorybookConfig } */

const config = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss",
    {
      name: "@storybook/addon-styling",
      options: {
        postCss: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/preact-vite",
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
};
export default config;
```

preview.js

```
/** @type { import('@storybook/preact').Preview } */

import "../src/main.css";

const preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/,
      },
    },
  },
};

export default preview;
```

postcss.config.cjs

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

tailwind.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{astro,html,js,jsx,md,mdx,svelte,ts,tsx,vue}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("@tailwindcss/typography"),
    require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
    require("@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio"),
  ],
};
```